# ''More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression'' postgres error

Tags: postgresql, error, request

I am trying to realize a postgres request :

```
select distinct nom_reg_12 
from region_15,repartition 
where st_intersects(region_15.geom,
                   (select geom 
                   from repartition 
                   where id_espece='Tetrarti'))=true;
```

but i get the following error :

> More than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

in the first time I tried this and it work fine :

```
select distinct nom_reg_12 
from region_15,repartition 
where st_intersects(region_15.geom,repartition.geom)=true;
```

and then I tried this a part to get the geometry I want :

```
select geom from repartition where id_espece='Tetrarti'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can move your condition outside of the subquery.
ST_Intersects works on 1 row (for each geometry) at a time, so if you use a subquery it must also return just one row, and you probably have more than 1 'Tetrarti' row

```
select distinct nom_reg_12 
from region_15,repartition 
where id_espece='Tetrarti'
and st_intersects(region_15.geom,
                   repartition.geom)=true;
```

Comment: why is the  = true needed? the st_intersects is a boolean function...

Comment: @ziggy it isn't needed. `st_intersects` returns a boolean so you may compare it to true/false or omit the comparison, which is the same as comparing to `true`.

Comment: so by that logic you can st_intersects()=false and that will return the geometries that do not intersect?

Comment: @ziggy yes st_intersects()=false is the same as ST_Disjoint()

Comment: @JGH thats a neat trick because the st_intersects uses an index where as st_disjoin does not. I usually go with the left join+not null option for not intersects but il be curious to see what the performance is with  st_intersects()=false